# Energy Conservation in Pair Annihilation and Feynman-Stuckelberg Interpretation

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, dirac-equation, antimatter, arrow-of-time

The textbook "Modern Particle Physics" by Mark Thomson on p. (98) reads:

> In the left plot, an electron of energy $E$ emit a photon with energy $2E$ and, to conserve energy, produces an electron with energy $-E$, which being a negative energy solution of the Dirac equation propagates backwards in time.

[image]

Now, since the photon has energy $2E$, but the electron which produced it had only $E$, where does the other $E$ come from? How does having an electron  with energy $-E$ somehow provide this missing energy E? The sum of energies should be $E + (-E) = 0$. Similarly, the charges of the two electrons $-q + (-q) = -2q$, which, of course, is not a zero net charge which the photon has. I read somewhere that we add the energies like this $E - (-E) = 2E$ and I think we would add the charges in that manner too. But why do we do it like that? Please provide only the hints to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Feynman Stuckelberg convention is coming from the invariance of the unitary evolution operator $U=e^{-iEt}$, hence when $t<0$, $E<0$. You have to consider the notion of time to understand the charge and the energy conservation. Think of time as flowing from left to right direction. Then everything is conserved.

One important point is, there are some problems with this convention, as were with Dirac. Positrons do not have $-ve$ energy, but it helps to visualize the situation.

Comment: Time flowing from left to right is the ordinary direction of time per this figure.